# RHEL7 selinux problems trying to run sshd via xinetd - sshd_net_t transition causes login failure

Tags: ssh, selinux, rhel7

I'm trying to set up sshd to run under xinetd on an RHEL7 server.  I run sshd on an alternate port, using xinetd to limit what IPs can connect.

This works fine on RHEL6, and also on RHEL7 if I disable SELinux.  However, the targeted SELinux policy on RHEL7 is preventing it.

Unfortunately, it's not logging much useful in /var/log/audit when it fails.  My connection attempt yields two lines of successful CRYPTO_KEY_USER operations, and then this (a single line, which I've wrapped):

```
type=USER_LOGIN msg=audit(1485378997.248:18523): pid=6812 uid=0 
auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 
subj=system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 
msg='op=login acct="(unknown)" exe="/usr/sbin/sshd" 
hostname=? addr=A.B.C.D terminal=ssh res=failed'
```

`audit2why` doesn't even acknowledge that a problem exists.  I'd guess it is looking for DENY events or something like that, not failures.

I added debug logging to sshd and found this (not wrapped this time):

```
debug1: SELinux support enabled [preauth]
debug3: ssh_selinux_change_context: setting context from 'system_u:system_r:sshd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023' to 'system_u:system_r:sshd_net_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023' [preauth]
debug3: privsep user:group 74:74 [preauth]
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 74/74 [preauth]
debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
Write failed: Permission denied [preauth]
```

I presume this is my problem - the transition from sshd_t to sshd_net_t.   However, without any useful information from the audit logs, I've reached the limit of my SElinux debugging skills.

A colleague suggested I review the audit logs from a successful connection in permissive mode.  Unfortunately, there's no mention of a successful action as sshd_net_t.    Here are the relevant log entries:  http://pastebin.com/raw/9sSVpgLq

I did see some relevant information on the redhat bug tracker, but it didn't get me very far toward a solution. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1008580

Comment: Is this even supported anymore? It wasn't a very good idea to begin with. And besides, you can set up a firewall zone to do this, and then you can just run sshd normally.

Comment: Ahhh....SELinux is actively supported and there are many people working with Linux systems.  In Linux systems operating in the government (esp military constabulary) enforcing mode is a requirement.

Comment: Michael is probably asking about running ssh as a xinetd service, not SELinux. Can you elaborate on the use case for using SSH as a xinetd service?

Comment: systemd does not provide the ability to limit what IPs can connect to a service; xinetd does.  You are right that iptables/firewalld can restrict access to the port; we prefer to use both methods in concert.  http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/inetd.html "That said, there are a couple of useful features that systemd does not support, for example IP ACL management."  That blog entry also mentions something about tcpwrap support, which i guess i will investigate.  Regardless, I'm really curious about this problem.

Comment: Xinetd has no place in this chain. Why make this more difficult? Are there requirements that you're not articulating in the question?

Comment: As i described in the comment above yours, there is a requirement to have (xinetd or systemd or whatever) do ip address ACLs before spawning sshd.  systemd doesn't support IP acls AFAICT.  I understand that firewalls can do this at the network layer - and in fact we use both methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that certain SELinux rules are not audited by default.  Running:

```
semanage dontaudit off
```

enables audit logging even on "dontaudit" rules in the policy.

Once I did that, it was easy to track down the missing SELinux permissions (which were `allow sshd_net_t inetd_t:tcp_socket (read|write);`).